# mutate_impl error in dplyr/lubridate add date time

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate, tidyverse

Using the `lubridate` package I want to add seconds (for the purpose of the example) to a `"POSIXct", "POSIXt"` field in a tibble.

```
b <- structure(list(`"a"` = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), Date_time = structure(c(1506694322, 
1506694270, 1506693970, 1506693897, 1506693849), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("\"a\"", "Date_time"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

b %>%
  mutate(tol_lower = Date_time - second(2),
         tol_lower = Date_time + second(30))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Why is this?  I appreciate i can calculate hours, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Additional points:

-I've tried as.Date, which gives the same error.

-I can add seconds directly without issue: `tol_lower = Date_time - 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whyn't use this?

```
b %>% mutate(tol_lower = Date_time - 2,
             tol_upper = Date_time + 30)
```

In case you want to add hours to given date then simply use `Date_time + 2*60*60` (i.e. 2 hours added to `Date_time`).

Also `?second` clearly says that `x` in `second(x)` is a "date-time object" but in your case you are trying to pass an integer.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked well, but may be you should have elaborated it a bit more.. :)